# tor doesn't open dns port

Tags: configuration, dns

I try to create a middlebox to redirect tor trafic but i have a problem. Tor doesn't create dns port 5353 as i configured in /etc/tor/torrc

```
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040 IsolateClientAddr IsolateClientProtocol IsolateDestAddr IsolateDestPort
DNSPort 5353
```

See my netstat :

```
root@debian:~/Documents# netstat -plnt
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat        PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      668/tor             
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9040          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      668/tor             
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      580/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      580/sshd            
root@debian:~/Documents#
```

ty for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Your netstat command is looking for listening TCP ports explicitly: netstat -pln**t**

DNS will be UDP, not TCP.